# Scala NoClassDefFoundError when running from command line

Tags: scala, command-line

What am I doing wrong here? All signs point to a silly configuration issue, but I can not figure out why I'm getting that the class can't be found.

```
> cat Exercise03.scala | head -4
package com.me.scala.chapter04.Exercise03

object Exercise03 extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {

> scalac Exercise03.scala

> ls -1 com/me/scala/chapter04/*.class
com/me/scala/chapter04/Exercise03$.class
com/me/scala/chapter04/Exercise03.class

> javap -classpath com/me/scala/chapter04 Exercise03 | head -2
Compiled from "Exercise03.scala"
public final class com.me.scala.chapter04.Exercise03 extends java.lang.Object {

> scala -cp com/me/scala/chapter04 com.me.scala.chapter04.Exercise03
No such file or class on classpath: com.me.scala.chapter04.Exercise03   

> scala -cp com/me/scala/chapter04 Exercise03
No such file or class on classpath: com/me/scala/chapter04/Exercise03.class

> scala -cp com/me/scala/chapter04/ Exercise03                                                                                                                                                 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Exercise03 (wrong name: com/me/scala/chapter04/Exercise03)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't compile with an output path (`-d` option) so you don't run it with a class-path. I don't know why javap worked as you invoked it, but it apparently has a special case that the Scala launcher does not. The entries in a class-path are the base directories (or JAR files) within which to build a path name in which each nested package name is a correspondingly nested directory name.

So, in a nutshell:

```
% scalac Foo.scala
% scala Foo
```

or:

```
% scalac -d target/main Foo.scala
% scala -classpath target/main Foo
```

etc.